# How to use node's IP instead of pod IP for egress using IPv6?

Tags: kubernetes, calico, kubernetes-egress

I'm using dual-stack Kubernetes (1.23.2 with Calico as CNI). From one of my pods I want to create a connection to another device which is external to the Kubernetes installation. The connection will pass through an (also external) LB / firewall.

When I try to create an IPv6 connection, I see that the internal **pod** IP address is used as source address (which is of course outside the Kubernetes cluster not routable). To my understanding the **node** IP should be used:

> For example, if a pod in an overlay network attempts to connect to an IP address outside of the cluster, then the node hosting the pod uses SNAT (Source Network Address Translation) to map the non-routable source IP address of the packet to the node’s IP address before forwarding on the packet.
> https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/about/about-kubernetes-egress

Is there some switch / configuration (parameter) to force the use of the node IP instead of the pod IP?

BTW: This only appears for IPv6 - IPv4 communication used as expected the node IP.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster (your config file)? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: The K8S version you find in the question. I'm using kubespray on baremetal.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the root cause was that IPv4 NAT is enabled by default while IPv6 is not when installing calico using kubespray. (It looks that currently even the appropriate config parameter `nat_outgoing_ipv6` is not documented.)

To fix the problem, you need to edit the IPv6 IPPool

```
kubectl edit ippool default-pool-ipv6
```

and add

```
natOutgoing: true
```